# Admin page: form with enctype="multipart/form-data" does not transfer its data

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, uploads, forms

I'm googeling for hours now but can't find anything to my problem:

I'm building a plugin and want to embed a file input in its admin page. For this reason I'm giving the form-element the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and I'm trying to access the file via `$_FILES`, but it is empty!
Same with `$_POST`.

Without `enctype="multipart/form-data"` at least the filename and the other form fields appear in `$_POST`.

I'm wondering if WordPress is removing direct access to these superglobals or somehow else preventing this regular way of uploading files.

I've read a lot about hooks and posting all forms to *admin_post.php* or *admin_ajax.php* but since my upload functionality is located in a class that's part of a big library with autoloading etc. it's not an option for me. My form is sending it's data to the current admin page (I tried it without the `action`-Attribute but also specifying it `action="admin.php?page=XYZ"` but nothing worked).

I would be thankful for every hint!

Comment: Have you seen this - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_edit_form_tag

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload in a custom folder you can use the following function.  Add the function in functions.php

```
function upload_user_file( $file = array(),$path ) {
    if(!empty($file)) 
    {


        $upload_dir=$path;
        $uploaded=move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $upload_dir.$file['name']);
        if($uploaded) 
        {
            echo "uploaded successfully ";

        }else
        {
            echo "some error in upload " ;print_r($file['error']);  
        }
    }

}
```

Make a form in your template file like this:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file">
    <input type="submit" name="upload">
</form>
```

Call the upload function in template file like before `get_header()` function:

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {

       if( ! empty( $_FILES ) ) 
       {
          $file=$_FILES['file'];   // file array
          $upload_dir=wp_upload_dir();
          $path=$upload_dir['basedir'].'/myuploads/';  //upload dir.
          if(!is_dir($path)) { mkdir($path); }
          $attachment_id = upload_user_file( $file ,$path);

       }
    }
```